# Print stream value in gdb - C++

Tags: c++, stream, gdb

I'm trying to see the value of stream (ifstream, but it should work for all kind of streams I guess).
The example code could look like this:

```
stringstream in("One Two Three Four Five");
while(in)
cout << in;
```

I was trying to do it in following ways but none of them seems to work:

```
(gdb) print in
(gdb) call cout << in
(gdb) call in.getline()
```

... and so on.

Is there any way, to see the value of the stream?

Comment: Is it a `stringstream` or an `ifstream`? There is no way to get a file's content this way!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have the package with the `libstdc++` library compiled with the debugging flags.

I have the `libstdc++6-8-dbg` package installed and now I can view all the stream object data in `gdb`.

Comment: Sorry but this caused further problems for me. I'm using WSL(Windows Subsystem for Windows) Debian btw.

Comment: I downloaded libstdc++6-10-dbg and it doesn't work

Comment: @Autechre try `export LD_PRELOAD=<your path to the debug libstdc++.so>` before debugging your program, e.g. `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so`

Answer (score 4):

I got what I needed by recompiling everything (not just one or two translation units) with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. Then I can just do

```
(gdb) p is.tellg()
$21 = {_M_off = 0, _M_state = {__count = 0, __value = {__wch = 0, __wchb = "\000\000\000"}}}
(gdb)
```

where `is` is a `std::istream&`. Previously I was getting

```
(gdb) p is.tellg()
Couldn't find method std::istream::tellg
(gdb) p is
```

Also, when I only rebuilt one compilation unit, it ran but crashed with

```
...
305d85d000-305d85e000 r--p 0005d000 fd:01 1180082                        /lib64/libfreebl3.so
305d85e000-305d85f000 rw-p 0005e000 fd:01 118
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003052e35215 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

See also: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Solution**

To find out which version of libstdc++-dbg package will work: type `apt-cache search libstdc++ | grep dbg` in the terminal. Find the latest version package, which is in the format `libstdc++6-5-dbg`.

On one of my machines `libstdc++6-5-dbg` works, while on the other one `libstdc++6-8-dbg` does.

<strike>Installing `libstdc++6-8-dbg` worked for me too. I have a 18.04 bionic beaver. Earlier I tried installing a dbg version that matched my libstdc++-dev version, but that did not work.</strike>

**Thorough Solution:**

1. If you see `<incomplete type>` when trying to print a string inside gdb, then you need to install a packages similar to `libstdc++6-8-dbg` available for your dist.  Run `ldd <executable>` . You will see an output like:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe4cbea000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f523eab1000)
    libmpi.so.12 => /opt/mpich-3.2/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007f523e36c000)
```

If you do not see a debug version in the `libstdc++.so.6` link, then try to locate the corresponding library using `locate libstdc++.so.6`. Include that debug directory with the `-L` flag during linking stage of your executable. Also include the same directory in `-rpath` to include it in the runtime library. Recompile your executable. Run again `ldd <executable>` to verify if the debug directory is included or not. This takes care of the incomplete type.

2. Now while trying to print a string if you see an output like this:

```
$1 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    _M_p = 0x7fffffffda70 "dump-000"}, _M_string_length = 8, {_M_local_buf = "dump-000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", 
    _M_allocated_capacity = 3472328284420535652}}
```

then your gdb version needs a pretty printer. First verify that the gdb is installed with python support, which can be found out by typing `show configuration` in gdb:

```
(gdb) show configuration
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
             --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/home/zephyr/utils/gdb-8.3-install/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/home/zephyr/utils/gdb-8.3-install/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --without-lzma
             --without-babeltrace
             --without-intel-pt
             --disable-libmcheck
             --without-mpfr
             --without-python
             --without-guile
             --disable-source-highlight
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/home/zephyr/utils/gdb-8.3-install/lib/debug (relocatable)
```

Look inside `gdb-datadir` by typing `ls /home/zephyr/utils/gdb-8.3-install/share/gdb`. If you do not see a python folder, then your `gdb` needs to be installed with `python` support. Ensure that `python-dev` is installed before configuring, compiling and installing your `gdb`. Now install the pretty printers by following the instructions given on this page: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport.

Congratulations! you now have pretty printers installed.

Comment: This answer has been given before. Upvote if you agree, do not repeat the answer

Comment: I do not have enough reputations either to comment or to upvote. I am only pointing out that this particular package worked for me even though I have a different version of libstdc++.

Comment: Shared a more general answer that works on different machines.

Comment: This helped me. In my case just installing `sudo apt install libstdc++6-8-dbg` did not work.

I forced `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug` before running gdb and the debug version of the library was correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `print in.str()` or even `print in.str().c_str()`

because [`stringstream` has a `str` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/) giving a `std::string`,  and [`string` has a `c_str` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) giving a `char*`

Comment: Yes, in both cases I get: "Couldn't find method std::ifstream::str" Did I missed some options for gdb to include c++ libraries?

Comment: `ifstream` doesn't have a method named `str`

Answer (score 0):

No. The entire idea of a stream is that it reads data as it becomes available, be it from a hard drive, from the network, or from whatever. For example, I could write a class supporting streams that just indefinitely emitted the character 'a'.

If you want to do this, you're going to just have to write a helper function in your own program which reads the required data from the stream.

Comment: but it is a `stringstream` not an ordinary file based `ifstream` !

Comment: In the top of the question, he mentions using `ifstream`!

Comment: When I'm debugging stringstream I try things like this: `print in.str()` and I get `Couldn't find method std::stringstream::str`. How come? It is stringstream method. And when I use ifstrem, i do: `call cout << in.get()` and again I get `Couldn't find method std::ifstream::get`

Answer (score 0):

`(gdb) call 'operator<<'(_ZSt4cout, your_object)`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error from gdb std::ifstream::is_open method not found.  My search for an answer led me to this thread.  If you are working in Cygwin, package libstdc++6-8-dbg doesn't exist.  I found that installing Cygwin package gcc-debuginfo worked.