# Why do I get an <incomplete type> message for a ifstream object in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

If I run the following code in the gdb debugger and type in print inFile, I get the message "incomplete type".

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("testFile.txt");
  std::cout<<"In the debugger if I print the inFile variable at this point I get the incomplete type message";
  inFile.close();
}
```

This makes it rather difficult to debug. Anyone knows what the reason for this might be?

---

This is how I compile the file:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

Here is the complete GDB output:

```
>> gdb main
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from main...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ac2: file main.cpp, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ~/main

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:3
3   int main() {
(gdb) n
4     std::ifstream inFile;
(gdb) 
5     inFile.open("testFile.txt");
(gdb) print inFile
$1 = <incomplete type>
(gdb)
```

---

I used the approach ks1322 described in his post and got the following message for

```
dpkg --list | grep libstdc++

ii  libstdc++-5-dev:amd64                      5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5                       amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                           5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5                       amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

The
`sudo apt-get install libstdc++`

displays

```
libstdc++6                         libstdc++6-5-dbg-m68k-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg                 libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips64-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips64el-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-mips-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dev                 libstdc++6-5-dbg-mipsel-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armel-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-powerpc-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-dev-armhf-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-powerpcspe-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-doc                 libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-pic                 libstdc++6-5-dbg-ppc64el-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armel-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-s390x-cross
libstdc++6-4.7-pic-armhf-cross     libstdc++6-5-dbg-sh4-cross
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg                 libstdc++6-5-dbg-sparc64-cross
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross     libstdc++6-alpha-cross
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross     libstdc++6-arm64-cross
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross   libstdc++6-armel-cross
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross   libstdc++6-armhf-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg                 libstdc++6-hppa-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross     libstdc++6-m68k-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross     libstdc++6-mips64-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross     libstdc++6-mips64el-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross   libstdc++6-mips-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross   libstdc++6-mipsel-cross
libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-s390x-cross     libstdc++6-powerpc-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg                   libstdc++6-powerpcspe-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg-alpha-cross       libstdc++6-ppc64-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg-arm64-cross       libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg-armel-cross       libstdc++6-s390x-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg-armhf-cross       libstdc++6-sh4-cross
libstdc++6-5-dbg-hppa-cross        libstdc++6-sparc64-cross
```

Comment: Post the gdb output.

Comment: My bad, I edited the code to make it compile. The gdb output is simply: <incomplete type>

Comment: Post the complete gdb output, including how you attempt to print  the stream variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install debug symbols for libstdc++ (this is where `std::ifstream` resides). See [here the similar issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5dwtbb/gdb_looking_into_streams/) for `std::stringstream`:

> That's caused by gdb not having debug information for your standard
>   library. It's not enough to compile your program with -g, because it's
>   the code in your standard library that defines those types. For
>   example, if you're using gcc with a Debian based system, there's a
>   -dbg version of libstdc++ that you can install. Example:

So you need to install this package `libstdc++<your version>-dbg` with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++<your version>-dbg
```

Replace `<your version>` with your version of libstdc++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will probably fix it, but how can I find the libstdc++ version that I need to install?

Comment: One way is `dpkg --list | grep libstdc++`.

Comment: Or you can type `sudo apt-get install libstdc++` and press Tab to autocomplete the version and finally type `-dbg`.

Comment: I updated the answer to display the output of these commands you suggested. I will remove any redundant info after it hopefully gets fixed.

Comment: I think it should be `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-5-dbg` but I can't verify it because I have no Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

A useful solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754863/11867786